# Binding enabled state of button in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just getting my feet wet with Ember.js, and I've hit something that I'm sure I'm not understanding.

I've got a selected object controller.  It has content, which is an Ember.Object, which is the currently selected model.  The model has a property (isDirty), and basically I'd like my save button on my form to be enabled only when the object is dirty and needs to be saved.

I've managed to bind up the form just fine, but the isEnabledBinding property on the save button is either not doing anything or I'm not hooking up the binding properly.

I've prepared a jsfiddle demonstrating my basic set up.

http://jsfiddle.net/blargity/fqc73/1/

How do I get the button to be enabled only when isDirty is true?  The bindings should also work if the content property on the selected object controller changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `isEnabled` property on `Ember.Button`. You need to bind to the `disabled` property.

One possibility is to create a custom `Ember.Button` which handles this for you, see http://jsfiddle.net/LabpW/.

**Handlebars**:

```
{{#view App.SaveModelButton modelBinding="model"}}Save{{/view}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
App.SaveModelButton = Ember.Button.extend({
    disabledBinding: Ember.Binding.not('model.isDirty')
});
```

The used `Ember.Binding.not` is just a shortcut for writing your own computed property, which would look like this:

```
App.SaveModelButton = Ember.Button.extend({
    disabled: function() {
        return !Ember.getPath(this, 'model.isDirty');
    }.property('model.isDirty').cacheable()
});
```

---

I also refactored your code a bit:

- You mixed `create` and `extend`: use `create` for instances and `extend` for classes. There is a good blog post about [this](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/)
- It's kind of a convention to use lowerCase for instances and UpperCase for classes, so it should be `App.controller` instead of `App.Controller`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, and correcting my style issues.

Comment: This works great, but there's a deprecation warning on Ember.Button in recent Ember. (I'm using v1.0.pre-48-g138fbdf)

Answer (score 14):

I found a way to do this without using the now-deprecated Ember.Button.

In the handlebars template:

```
<button {{action "save" target="controller"}} {{bindAttr disabled="view.isNotDirty"}}>Save</button>
```

In the view:

```
isNotDirty: function(){ 
    return !this.get('controller.content.isDirty') 
}.property('controller.content.isDirty').cacheable()
```

(With the version of Ember I have, Ember.Binding.not does not exist. Maybe I need to update, but the docs don't show it either so perhaps it was actually removed.)

Comment: In Ember 1.4.0-beta.6, the correct binding is `{{bind-attr disabled=...}}`

Comment: Typically bind-attr is used with a property inside a controller but sometimes the property is in view itself. This answer is great since it shows exactly how to do this (using the 'view.' prefix).