# Using bindAttr to disable a button if the ArrayController contains no Models in Ember

Tags: templates, binding, ember.js

I have a template that contains a button:

```
<button {{action clearAll}} >Clear All</button>
```

The template's Controller is an `ArrayController`. I would like the button to be disabled if the ArrayController's content property contains zero items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding enabled state of button in Ember.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867696/binding-enabled-state-of-button-in-ember-js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to use *[computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/)*. Computed properties allow you to make a calculation based on Controller state rather than a raw boolean property (essentially creating a getter backed by multiple properties or a property of a different type).

In order for this function to fire bindings correctly, you need to declare which properties the function depends on - which properties should cause an update if they are modified. You do this using : `.property('content.length')'. In this case the function depends on a single property, but it could depend on more than one.

In the template:

```
<button {{action clearAll}} {{bindAttr disabled="anyEntries"}}>Clear All</button>
```

In the controller:

```
  anyEntries: function() {
    return this.get('content.length') == 0;
  }.property('content.length')
```